# Standard Enthought Canopy Install on Linux Not Working

Tags: linux, enthought

I am trying to install 32 bit Enthought Canopy on 64 bit Linux, Ubuntu 14.10 specifically. I followed the installation instructions here: http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/quick-start/install_linux.html

After downloading the file, I ran the command (without sudo):

```
bash canopy-1.4.1-rh5-32.sh
```

After accepting the license terms, I accepted the default install location but got the following error message:

```
[/home/userX/Canopy32] >>> 
Installing to /home/userX/Canopy32 ... please wait
The databases in [/usr/share/ubuntu/applications, /usr/share/gnome/applications,   /usr/local/share/applications, /usr/share/applications] could not be updated.
done.
```

I did not know what to make of the error and proceeded to cd back to the home directory from the directory where I had saved the downloaded install file. Per Enthought's instructions, I ran the command:

```
Canopy32/canopy
```

Note that Enthought's instructions call for Canopy/canopy to be used. I am either in the wrong place or there is only a 'Canopy32' folder, not a 'Canopy' folder.

After running the 'Canopy32/canopy' command, I got the following error message:

```
userX@userX-laptop:~$ Canopy32/canopy
No handlers could be found for logger "canopy.app.bootstrap"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/userX/Canopy32/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.rh5-x86/__boot__.py", line 9, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/app/bootstrap.py", line 2220, in main
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/app/bootstrap.py", line 2186, in send_bug_report
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'run_factory_reset'
```

When I use the Unity Dash to search for Canopy, the Canopy icon with the blue rainbow above it appears but when I click it, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?